# Is Facebook/Twitter account linked to currently signed in Foursquare user account. Foursquare API

Tags: facebook, foursquare

I am building iPhone app, which uses Foursquare API. My app needs to know if Facebook/Twitter account is linked to currently signed in foursquare user account. I am not sure how to get this info via Foursquare API.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `/users/self` API endpoint. In the `contact` block, it will contain the user's Facebook and/or Twitter information, if available.